# Why is image not appearing in HTML?

Tags: html, css, image

So iam a first time HTML and CSS user, and was making a website using a YouTube video, however i reached a stage where i want to show the backround image onto the screen however ive followed the video exactly and it only shows my logo image and not the background image.

This was the youtube video : https://youtu.be/5bMdjkfvONE
I got up to 1:00:0 into the video after that it no longer worked like in the video.

```css
/* Master Styles */
body {
    margin: 0px;

}

.container {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr;
}

/* Nav Styles*/
.nav-wrapper{
    display:flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    padding: 40px;
}

.left-side{
    display:flex;

}

.nav-wrapper > .left-side > div {
    margin-right: 20px;
    font-size: 0.9em;
    text-transform:uppercase;
}

.nav-link-wrapper {
    height: 22px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid transparent;
    transition: border-bottom 0.5s;
}

.nav-link-wrapper a {
    color:blue;
    text-decoration: none;
    transition: color 0.5s;
}

.nav-link-wrapper:hover{
    border-bottom: 1px solid black;
}

.nav-link-wrapper a:hover{
    color: black;
}

/* Portfolio Styles */
.portfolio-items-wrapper {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
}

.portfolio-item-wrapper {
    position: relative;
}

.portfolio-img-background {
    height: 350px;
    width: 100%;
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;

}

.img-text-wrapper {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    height: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    padding-left: 100px;
    padding-right: 100px;
}

.logo-wrapper img {
    width: 50%;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.subtitle {
    font-weight: 600;
    color: darkblue;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Mathews Joy</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
</head>

<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="nav-wrapper">
            <div class="left-side">
                <div class="nav-link-wrapper">
                    <a href="https://www.linkedin.com/in/mathews-joy/">Personal LinkedIn Page</a>
                </div>

                <div class="nav-link-wrapper">
                    <a href="https://www.instagram.com/?hl=en">Personal Instagram Page</a>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="right-side">
                <div class="brand">
                    MATHEWS JOY
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="content-wrapper">
            <div class="portfolio-items-wrapper">

                <div class="portfolio-item-wrapper">
                    <div class="portfolio-img-backround" style="background-image:url(images/portfolio1.jpg)"></div>

                    <div class="img-text-wrapper">
                        <div class="logo-wrapper">
                            <img src="images/network.jpg">
                        </div>

                        <div class="subtitle">
                            Technology Intership at the Bright Network (December 2020)
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="portfolio-item-wrapper">
                    <div class="portfolio-img-backround" style="background-image:url(images/portfolio3.jpg)"></div>

                    <div class="img-text-wrapper">
                        <div class="logo-wrapper">
                            <img src="images/network.jpg">
                        </div>

                        <div class="subtitle">
                            Certications completed during time at university (2020 - 2023)
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="portfolio-item-wrapper">
                    <div class="portfolio-img-backround" style="background-image:url(images/portfolio2.jpg)"></div>

                    <div class="img-text-wrapper">
                        <div class="logo-wrapper">
                            <img src="images/network.jpg">
                        </div>

                        <div class="subtitle">
                            Volunteering and Work Experiences
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

                
            </div>
        </div>


    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: In your HTML code, there's a typo in the class `portfolio-img-background`. That might be the cause, since without that class the element will have zero height => no visible background image.

Comment: @Johannes Thanks alot that was the mistake! a silly one ahah

Answer (score 0):

It's because there are no images at the URL's you are using.  What's more, you need to apply a height to the elements that have the background images. I only did it for one of them below.

```css
/* Master Styles */
body {
    margin: 0px;

}

.container {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr;
}

/* Nav Styles*/
.nav-wrapper{
    display:flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    padding: 40px;
}

.left-side{
    display:flex;

}

.nav-wrapper > .left-side > div {
    margin-right: 20px;
    font-size: 0.9em;
    text-transform:uppercase;
}

.nav-link-wrapper {
    height: 22px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid transparent;
    transition: border-bottom 0.5s;
}

.nav-link-wrapper a {
    color:blue;
    text-decoration: none;
    transition: color 0.5s;
}

.nav-link-wrapper:hover{
    border-bottom: 1px solid black;
}

.nav-link-wrapper a:hover{
    color: black;
}

/* Portfolio Styles */
.portfolio-items-wrapper {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
}

.portfolio-item-wrapper {
    position: relative;
}

.portfolio-img-background {
    height: 350px;
    width: 100%;
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;

}

.img-text-wrapper {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    height: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    padding-left: 100px;
    padding-right: 100px;
}

.logo-wrapper img {
    width: 50%;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.subtitle {
    font-weight: 600;
    color: darkblue;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Mathews Joy</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
</head>

<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="nav-wrapper">
            <div class="left-side">
                <div class="nav-link-wrapper">
                    <a href="https://www.linkedin.com/in/mathews-joy/">Personal LinkedIn Page</a>
                </div>

                <div class="nav-link-wrapper">
                    <a href="https://www.instagram.com/?hl=en">Personal Instagram Page</a>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="right-side">
                <div class="brand">
                    MATHEWS JOY
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="content-wrapper">
            <div class="portfolio-items-wrapper">

                <div class="portfolio-item-wrapper">
                    <div class="portfolio-img-backround" style="background-image:url(images/portfolio1.jpg)"></div>

                    <div class="img-text-wrapper">
                        <div class="logo-wrapper">
                            <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150

C/O https://placeholder.com/">
                        </div>

                        <div class="subtitle">
                            Technology Intership at the Bright Network (December 2020)
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="portfolio-item-wrapper">
                    <div class="portfolio-img-backround" style="background-image:url(https://via.placeholder.com/150); height: 200px"></div>

                    <div class="img-text-wrapper">
                        <div class="logo-wrapper">
                            <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150

C/O https://placeholder.com/">
                        </div>

                        <div class="subtitle">
                            Certications completed during time at university (2020 - 2023)
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="portfolio-item-wrapper">
                    <div class="portfolio-img-backround" style="background-image:url(images/portfolio2.jpg)"></div>

                    <div class="img-text-wrapper">
                        <div class="logo-wrapper">
                            <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150

C/O https://placeholder.com/">
                        </div>

                        <div class="subtitle">
                            Volunteering and Work Experiences
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

                
            </div>
        </div>


    </div>
</body>
</html>
```